# Autofac: register plugin constructor types at runtime

Tags: c#, plugins, module, autofac, caliburn

I'm working on a modular application where plugins are automatically loaded upon startup. The plugins work, however, instead of requiring the plugins to instantiate their own objects in the constructor, I want to do this automatically via autofac and reflection. The follow code works, but I'm wondering if Autofac has a way to do this more simply. Here's the snippet of code:

```
foreach (var module in modulesAssemblies)
        {
            try
            {
                var constructors =
                    module.DefinedTypes.First(k => k.Name == module.GetName().Name + "ViewModel")
                        .GetConstructors()[0];
                if (constructors == null) continue;
                foreach (var param in constructors.GetParameters())
                {
                    if (param.ParameterType.Name.StartsWith("I"))
                    {
                        var type = param.ParameterType;
                        var officalType =
                            module.DefinedTypes.Where(k => type.IsAssignableFrom(k) && k.Name != type.Name)
                                .Select(k => k);

                        builder.RegisterType(officalType.First()).As(type).AsImplementedInterfaces();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }

        }
```

I'm using Caliburn.Micro (hence + "ViewModel"). The plugins are loaded in the modulesAssemblies. They are already loaded via AssemblySource.Instance. I won't know what the plugins contain constructor wise, so I can't prebuild them as it's all going to be dynamic.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Autofac's [MEF integration](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mef.html) is in general really nice for handling plugins. Is there any particular reason you don't register all types in the plugin-dlls? I wouldn't expect plugin-dlls to contain that many classes. Registering all classes with their implemented interfaces should be much shorter (and easier to read).

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I was thinking I had to reflect through each of the constructors to implement what was needed. I'll try that. If it works I'll post back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I went with. It works:

```
    private static void RegisterAssemblyInterfaces(List<Assembly> modulesAssemblies, ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var baseType = typeof (IPluginView);
        var pluginAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && baseType != p);

        foreach (var assembly in pluginAssemblies)
        {
            var module = modulesAssemblies.FirstOrDefault(k => k.GetTypes().Any(v => v.IsAssignableFrom(assembly)));
            if (module == null) continue;
            var types = module.DefinedTypes.ToList();
            var interfaces = module.GetTypes().Where(k => k.IsInterface).ToList();
            if (!interfaces.Any()) continue;
            RegisterInterfaceToTypes(builder, interfaces, types);
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterInterfaceToTypes(ContainerBuilder builder, List<Type> interfaces, List<TypeInfo> types)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
                foreach (var type in types.Where(type => @interface.IsAssignableFrom(type) && @interface != type))
                    builder.RegisterType(type).As(@interface).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
```